# Creating a Power Mode Script in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, guid

**Background:**

I'm interning at a firm this fall in an IT support position, one of the ongoing projects I'm fielding is the development of useful powershell scripts for our machines. Recently we've been having trouble with our new machines constantly trying to reset their policy scheme. Adjusting the power mode slider to performance works to fix this issue. We're in talks with our vendor to find a more permanent solution. That being said, I would like to develop a script that can automatically adjust this slider. Here's a picture of the slider for clarity.

[image]

I have a few scripts that adjust power settings that I know for a fact work. Here's an example:

```
$activeScheme = cmd /c "powercfg /getactivescheme"

#Ensure active power scheme guid matches a set format
$regex = '(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}'
$asGuid =  [regex]::Match($activescheme,$regex).Value

#obtain necessary guid's to execute
$pwrGuid = '4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347'
$lidClosedGuid = '5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936'

#Set value, 0 for does nothing, 1 for sleep
cmd /c "powercfg /setdcvalueindex $asGuid $pwrGuid $lidClosedGuid 0"

#Apply setting
cmd /c "powercfg /s $asGuid"
```

Is there a similar route I can take to adjust this slider value? I tried pulling the guid of what I *believe* is the slider and substituting it into that example code. Any ideas on how to approach this? Thanks.